# IP Address range with subnetmask

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ip-address, subnet, whitelist

I'm quite new to how subnetmask is calculated.

We have a requirement to whitelist the range of IP addresses on our asp.net website.

```
199.83.128.1 - 199.83.135.254
198.143.32.1 - 198.143.63.254
149.126.72.1 - 149.126.79.254
103.28.248.1 - 103.28.251.254
185.11.124.1 - 185.11.127.254
45.64.64.0 - 45.64.67.255
192.230.64.1 - 192.230.127.254
```

ASP.NET IPSecurity has an option to block IP Address range, but with subnet mask.
e.g.

```
    <add ipAddress="xx.xx.xx.xx" subnetmask="x.x.x.x" allowed="true"/>
  </ipSecurity>
```

Could someone please help me how to come up address ranges list above using subnetmask?

Comment: I think this might be a better fit for Server Fault.  It has more to do with how to do network calculations than it has to do with programming, and once you know the values, you already know where these go in the web.config anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the .1 and .254s, they should be .0 and .255 for simplicity. I can't think that an organization controls a block of 1024 IPs except for the very first and very last one.

The canonical answer is https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work/226445 but I suppose it takes several hours to digest. Here's a "no understanding beyond basic math" version.

If you have a.b.x.0 - a.b.y.255 (with x ≤ y), then

- the number of /24s is n = y+1-x
- this is one subnet if n is a power of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256) **and** x is a multiple of n (`x = 0*n = 0` is OK), otherwise you have to split it up
- the 3rd-octet mask is then m = 256-n
- the resulting netmask is 255.255.m.0

Your result is (do feel free to check my math, it's your security not mine):

```
45.64.64.0   / 255.255.252.0
103.28.248.0 / 255.255.252.0
149.126.72.0 / 255.255.248.0
185.11.124.0 / 255.255.252.0
192.230.64.0 / 255.255.192.0
198.143.32.0 / 255.255.224.0
199.83.128.0 / 255.255.248.0
```

The math is the same for a.b.c.x - a.b.c.y, a.x.0.0 - a.y.255.255, and x.0.0.0 - y.0.0.0, except that we're not talking about /24s but IPs, /16s, and /8s, and that the netmasks become 255.255.255.m, 255.m.0.0, and m.0.0.0 respectively.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Of course, if someone wants to migrate this to serverfault, feel free :)